# Reads My Download As "Document"

Tags: system-installation

I tried to download 12.04 and 13.0 versions of Ubuntu on my Mac Mini which runs OS-X 10.7.5.

They download,but the disk images will not load into my recovery hard drive. What might I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu disc images (.ISO files) are meant to be burned to an external media, like a DVD or USB drive, not as a recovery image on a hard drive. The Ubuntu disc image is installation/testing media for Ubuntu, and is not meant to be burned to a recovery partition on a hard drive.

If you're trying to install Ubuntu, then burn the ISO image to a DVD with the following steps:

1. Insert the blank DVD
2. Start the Disk Utility application
3. Go to File --> Open Disk Image, then locate the ISO file on your hard drive
4. There will be an item representing the ISO image in the volumes list. Select the ISO image
5. Click Burn and follow the on screen instructions

Alternatively, if you prefer to use a USB drive as the installation media, the steps are a little more complicated, but are described in detail on Ubuntu's website [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

Comment: Will try USB flash drive.

Comment: Here in US,CDs only go to 700MB storage capacity. The Ubuntu loading files exceed that capacity,so one can't fit them on CDs.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant DVDs, not CDs. That was my bad. I'll edit that.